# Is the living shadow based on any real life myth or story?

Tags: lore, history-of-gaming, l5r

L5R is heavily based on Japanese and other Asian philosophy and stories, the story of the Kami, Ametarasu, lord moon etc.

Is the Living Shadow (first edition) or Lying Darkness as it is known later also drawn from a real source, or was this created for the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There's no *Living Shadow* outside of 1st Edition

L5R does not know a *Living Shadow* after the first edition. But it has [*Lying Darkness*](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Lying_Darkness) in all editions, and also allows making your own Yokai and Oni.

### You mean the *Lying Darkness*, right?

#### Edition history

Well, technically, the entity known as Lying Darkness was called Living Shadow in at least two sourcebooks during 1st edition:

- [*Way of the Shadowlands*, 2001](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/The_Way_of_the_Shadowlands), page 49 titled "The Shadowlands and the living Shadow", starting one paragraph with little to no substance. but again, that was retconned to Lying Darkness by 2nd Edition.
- It also had was *featured* with its own adventures in [*Way of Shadow*, 1998](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Way_of_Shadow), a campaign supplement that depicts several cases by an investigator. **However** even in it, the preferred term used is *Lying Darkness*, but uses Living Darkness and occasionally Living Shadow as synonyms.

This ambiguity was removed in 2nd Edition, when it was only called *Lying Darkness* in the future.

Anyway, the Lying Darkness is the permanent antagonist and pretty much the personification of the Void-before-creation. So we have to look at the [Japanese creation myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_creation_myth) in the [Nihon Shoki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon_Shoki) to see equivalents.

#### Japanese creation myth

> At the beginning the universe was immersed in a beaten and shapeless kind of matter (chaos), sunk in silence. Later there were sounds indicating the movement of particles. With this movement, the light and the lightest particles rose but the particles were not as fast as the light and could not go higher. Thus, the light was at the top of the Universe, and below it, the particles formed first the clouds and then Heaven, which was to be called [Takamagahara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takamagahara) (高天原, "High Plain of Heaven"). The rest of the particles that had not risen formed a huge mass, dense and dark, to be called Earth.

So, in Japanese creation, the chaos separated into light and Heaven and Earth. Then three gods and two essences (active and passive) formed. Beyond this first part of the creation, the void or chaos isn't named at all again. During the following age of gods, the [7 generations of gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamiyonanayo) spontaneously emerged. The last of them were Izanami and Izanagi.

Only **now** the latter two created Japan and had kids, among them Amaterasu,
Tsukuyomi and Susanoo as well as others.

##### Rokugan comparison

Barely anything between the Rokugan story and the Japanese creation myth matches:

- In the beginning there was [chaos and void](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Nothing).
- *something* was born from it.
- The Chaos was not named.

However, **that's all** that matches. As far as I can tell, it is generally considered a consensus in the fanbase that the *Lying Darkness* was invented for the game and fills the role of a BBEG. This is especially true when [Fu-Leng](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Fu_Leng), the original BBEG, and arch nemesis, is not available, and there's no gaijin outside force that could unify the country.

### If that's a Yokai, it's a [Nobiagari](https://yokai.com/nobiagari/)

伸上り / のびあがり

> Appearance: Nobiagari are dangerous shape-changing yōkai which can stretch to become extremely tall. When not stretching, they appear as shadowy or smokey, indistinct, rock-like shapes about 30 centimeters high.

These beasts sneak up as shadows and is occasionally described as a shadow itself. When you turn to it, it does stretch up to become super tall to send people running in fear. [Another description](https://yokai.fandom.com/wiki/Nobiagari) is mostly the same as from [Yokai.com](https://yokai.com/nobiagari/)

Comment: I was going to ask if you meant the Lying Darkness in L5R when you said Living Shadow

Comment: @CatLord that's what I commented first... before I figured I can make an answer from that and point to a very similar yokai at the same time!

Comment: Certainly learned something today and will need to revisit my mythology collection.

Comment: @From actually... check Way of Shadow, 1998, It does call it Lying Darkness! XD

Comment: @From reworded, after looking deeper, I had only read to the first few GM notes, where they use Lying Darkness exclusively. However, Amatsu-Mikaboshi does fit even less: he's a god of very late creation, long after the creation took place, and has absolutely nothing to do with creation itself.

Comment: I only play first edition (should have qualified that) bought all the books and have never bothered updating for a new edition, but yes Living Shadow or Lying Darkness.

Answer (score 0):

Trish's answer contains what I believe true of L5R and Japan. No direct parallels there. However, you asked for Asian philosophy and stories, which opens up some doors.

### Persia/Zoroastrianism

**Angra Mainyu**, or **[Ahriman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahriman)**, is a very close analogue. It is associated with a "world of darkness" (as well as [The World of Darkness](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Oblivion_(Discipline)#Standard_Powers), but I digress) and with shadows and evil. It is not wholly clear if it is an entity or merely the conceptual origin of all bad things, including bad thoughts, but it is nevertheless the enemy and opposite of Ahura Mazda, the creator deity.

### Mesopotamia/???

**[Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat)** is a personification of the dualistic principles of creation and destruction. She is the mother of all of creation, all the gods as well as all the monsters, and is identified with the primordial chaos, which exists before and will exist after all things.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for Asian philosophy and stories; they introduced in brief L5R's relationship to those and asked for whether there was a real source for a particular lore concept, which is pretty different. Note that if the question _was_ just "give me some Asian mythology around this concept" it wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: @doppelgreener My reading of the question disagrees with your interpretation. "L5R is heavily based on Japanese and other Asian philosophy and stories[.] Is the Living Shadow also drawn from a real source[?]" The OP seems to either be asking for "real" (i.e. "philosophy and stories") sources of inspiration for the Lying Darkness from the game, or for quotes from the designers on their inspiration, the latter option of which would match neither my nor Trish's answer.